# How to turn on smart screen filter using powershell?

Tags: powershell

Can some one suggest How to turn on smart screen filter for IE using power shell script?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me!!

```
Function EnableDisableSmartScreen($status) {

if($status -eq 1)
{
Write-Output "Enabling SmartScreen Filter..."
Remove-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System" -Name "EnableSmartScreen" 
Remove-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\MicrosoftEdge\PhishingFilter" -Name "EnabledV9" 
}
else
{
Write-Output "Disabling SmartScreen Filter..."
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System" -Name "EnableSmartScreen" -Type DWord -Value 0
If (!(Test-Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\MicrosoftEdge\PhishingFilter")) {
    New-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\MicrosoftEdge\PhishingFilter" -Force | Out-Null
}
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\MicrosoftEdge\PhishingFilter" -Name "EnabledV9" -Type DWord -Value 0
}
}
```